# Why its takes so much longer to fit model in sklearn.linear_model.QuantileRegressor then R model implementation?

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, linearmodels, quantile-regression

First I used R implementation quantile regression, and after that I used Sklearn implementation with the same quantile (tau) and alpha=0.0 (regularization constant). I am getting the same formulas! I tried many "solvers" and still the running time is much longer than that of R.

[Running time: Scikit-learn model vs R model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCXpC.png)

For example:

[Example: 40672 samples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt8zO.png)

In R model the default method is "br", and in Sklearn is "lasso". although I changed the method of R implementation to "lasso" the running time just shorter.

[Different methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xpbm.png)

Import and create a Data:

```py
import sklearn
print('sklearn version:', sklearn.__version__) # sklearn=1.0.1
import scipy
print('scipy version:', scipy.__version__) # scipy=1.7.2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import time

from sklearn.linear_model import QuantileRegressor

from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingRegressor
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri, pandas2ri

pandas2ri.activate() #activate conversion of Python pandas to R data structures
numpy2ri.activate() #activate conversion of Python numpy to R data structures

n_samples, n_features = 10000, 1
X = np.linspace(start=0.0,stop=2.0,num=n_samples).reshape((n_samples,n_features))
y = X+X*np.random.rand(n_samples,n_features)+1

X = pd.DataFrame(data=X, columns=['X'])
y = pd.DataFrame(data=y, columns=['y'])
```

Function for plot the data (with or without a line):

```py
from typing import NoReturn, List
import matplotlib.lines as mlines

def ScatterPlot(X : np.ndarray, Y : np.ndarray, title : str = "Default", line_coef : List[int] = None)->NoReturn:
    print(line_coef)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))
    ax.scatter(X, y, s=80, marker="P", c='green')
    xmin, xmax = ax.get_xbound()
    ymin, ymax = ax.get_ybound()
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel("X")
    plt.ylabel("Y")
    ax.set(xlim=(xmin, xmax), ylim=(ymin, ymax))#, aspect='equal')
    ax.grid()
    if line_coef is not None:
        p1, p2 = [0, line_coef[0]], [1, sum(line_coef)] 
        ymax = p1[1] + (p2[1] - p1[1]) / (p2[0] - p1[0]) * (xmax - p1[0])
        ymin = p1[1] + (p2[1] - p1[1]) / (p2[0] - p1[0]) * (xmin - p1[0])
        ax.add_line(mlines.Line2D([xmin,xmax], [ymin,ymax], color='red'))
    plt.show()
    
ScatterPlot(X=X, Y=y)
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRjDn.png)

Functions for getting the formulas:

```py
def R_get_formula():
    return (str(coef_R[0]) + ' + ' + ' + '.join(
        ['{} * [{}]'.format(str(a), str(b)) for a, b in zip(coef_R[1:].tolist(), ['X'])]))    

def get_formula_from_sklearn(regressor):
    return (str(regressor.intercept_) + ' + ' + ' + '.join(
            ['{} * [{}]'.format(str(a), str(b)) for a, b in zip(regressor.coef_.tolist(), regressor.feature_names_in_)]))
```

Fit the data and test the running time and the formulas:

```py
tau=0.95

_quantreg = importr("quantreg")  #import quantreg package from R
################# QuantileRegression R #################
start = time.time()
model_R = _quantreg.rq(formula='{} ~ .'.format(y.columns[0]), tau=tau, data=pd.concat(
            [y.reset_index(drop=True), X.loc[y.index, :].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1))
coef_R = numpy2ri.ri2py(model_R[0])
print('R tooks {} seconds to finish'.format(time.time()-start)) 
print("The formula is: {}".format(R_get_formula()))
print("Tau: {}".format(tau))
ScatterPlot(X=X, y=y, title="QuantileRegression - R",line_coef=coef_R)

################# QuantileRegression sklearn #################
start = time.time()
model_sklearn = QuantileRegressor(quantile=tau, alpha=0.0, solver='highs')
model_sklearn.fit(X, y)
print('Sklearn tooks {} seconds to finish'.format(time.time()-start)) 
print("The formula is: {}".format(get_formula_from_sklearn(model_sklearn)))
print("Tau: {}".format(tau))
ScatterPlot(X=X, y=y, title="QuantileRegression - sklearn",line_coef=[model_sklearn.intercept_] + list(model_sklearn.coef_))
```

[R_model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZkHA.png)
[Sklearn_model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXFRg.png)

Why its takes so much longer to fit model in sklearn then R model implementation?

Comment: Please show the code needed to produce both results, as well as the (example) data.

Comment: Perhaps statsmodels can be of use here, instead of scikit-learn; as an extra comparison.

Comment: I tried statsmodels before sklearn model but I didnt get the same formulas. (maybe because the features are not i.i.d). Scikit-learn has released a new version. The version includes Quantile Regression implementation - so why not to try?!.

Comment: Your R code is Python? What are you comparing? What is `QuantileRegressionR`? Show relevant imports.

Comment: There is no use without data for us to try and reproduce your results. Please provide (public) data that produces your problem. Create a [mcve].

Comment: what is QuantileRegressionR ???

Comment: As @StupidWolf implies, please also include the relevant library imports in both languages.

Comment: i'm having the same problem

Comment: I think sklearn knew about this algorithm being slow as per the docs: "Method used by scipy.optimize.linprog to solve the linear programming formulation. Note that the highs methods are recommended for usage with scipy>=1.6.0 because they are the fastest ones."

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented the fast quantile regression in Python that uses interior point method. It also supports cluster robust standard error. Please check it out here: https://github.com/mozjay0619/pyqreg.

There you will find install instructions and some examples. If you do end up using it, please give the link some credit (give the repo a star! Took me a long time to make this) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments by Mauricio, changing the solver to HiGHS `solver="highs"` works for some cases (at least, it solved my problem in my case). Btw, this may require installation of the solver.

See [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.QuantileRegressor.html?highlight=quantile#sklearn.linear_model.QuantileRegressor) for the use of parameter

If your data set is a bit larger there is a reported [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/22922) in their Github repo.